# How to check for quick oscillations without an oscilloscope

Tags: oscillator, 555

I'm working on a 555 timer oscillator circuit, and I'm trying to get an LED to blink. The LED turns on, but I'm not sure if it's blinking. I do not own an oscilloscope I've tried a few things, such as recording with a slow motion camera. Is there a good way to test it? I was thinking I might be able to hook up a transformer to it and check for a constant voltage.

Comment: You should share your schematic.

Comment: Try shaking the LED, you will see, as your eyes can detect pulsing if moved.

Comment: Did you know Audacity (free) has a scope view of audio so you can use the AUX in port or maybe the Mic port with a suitable voltage divider and series R to input the signal

Comment: speakers connected with a resistor make noise in the presence of unsteady current

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That's actually incredible. I've owned audacity for many years, and have never heard of that. However, I really don't want to damage my soundcard, and I'm not sure if the current is to high.

Comment: Use a scope probe 10:1 to Aux in high impedance 1V or 100K:11k or something like that, then choose input and press record

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Could you give me a link to a tutorial?

Comment: no. but you can try it with series R to limit current and shunt R to scale down V

Answer (score 2):

Use a [RC low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#RC_filter) and a multimeter.

Here's how:

- Connect a 10 kΩ resistor to the point you believe is oscillating.
- Connect a 10 µF capacitor between the resistor and ground
- Measure the voltage across the capacitor, let's call this voltage \$V_c\$

If \$V_c\$ is around 20-80% of the max value of the signal you believe is oscillating, then it's most likely oscillating.

If \$V_c\$ is around +99% of the max value of the signal you believe is oscillating, then it is most likely not oscillating.

---

Extra info:

Using a low pass filter in this configuration will give you the average value of the oscillating signal. So if it is 50% high and 50% low and it is a square wave signal that is between 0 V and 5 V. Then in an ideal world you will read 2.5 V across the capacitor.

If it is high 80% of the time then you will in an ideal world read \$0.8×5=4\$ V across the capacitor.

If it is high 100% of the time, then it's **not** oscillating, and you will therefor read 5 V.

Comment: Thanks! Could I do this with a 1 or a 100uF capacitor?

Comment: @HXGamer The higher the capacitance, the smoother your reading will be. And the longer time it will take for it to reach the average value. I'm not sure what you mean with a "1", but with a 100 µF capacitor, sure. With a 100 µF capacitor + a 10 kΩ resistor, I believe you will see the average value within a second. Or somewhere around there. If it would've been 1 F then you should expect around a minute if not more.

Comment: I used an 11.73kΩ resistor, and an 100uF capacitor. The supply voltage is 12.30V, and the output using the low pass filter was 3.41. That's ~27.7% of the supply voltage, however, I used a different resistor. Also, is there a way to determine the frequency and duty cycle of this signal?

Comment: @HXGamer Then the duty cycle appears to be 27.7%, if you want to get the frequency then you will have to make some other changes, but this is outside of the scope of this question. So this will be my last comment. I will still attempt to point you in the right direction for acquiring the frequency. **A**) Buy an oscilloscope (at least a DSO138), it will be some investment. **B**) Use a microcontroller (e.g. Arduino) and its internal timers. **C**) Make a charge pump and measure the voltage with 0.1–1 kΩ load.  **D**) Make a RC high-pass filter followed by envelope detector and trim R for -3dB.

Comment: Also, you can try to measure an AC component of signal: put a 0.1 uF capacitor in series to multimeter in AC mode. If there is no oscillations, measured value wil be close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't afford a scope a decent logic probe will tell you if a logic signal is pulsing. They are reasonably cheap and a quick test tool.

[image]

Comment: I used a logic probe a lot to debug digital circuits before I can afford my first oscilloscope :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to take a movie of your LED at a high rate.  I think most smartphones can film at 60 Hz.  Plot the amplitude of the pixel associated with the LED and see if there is a distinct frequency.  You might be able to say if your LED is blinking but might not be sure about the frequency due to aliasing.

Comment: If there's oscillating then it will be most likely in kHz range. 60Hz camera won't help you.

Comment: I tried that already, but @Chupacabras is correct. If it is infact oscillating, it's probably in the kHz range. The circuit is supposed to make an LED blink but I used to little resistor values